# SELECT and use the returned value in UPDATE in one SQL statement

Tags: sql

How to select a value from one table and use this value in the other update statement.

But using only one sql statement?

is it possible?

I have SQL

1. `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='hello-world';`

and the row stored use in this:

2. `UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='http://example.com' WHERE post_id={{here I need to put the value from the first statement liek first_table.ID or something}}`

How to do that in only one SQL statement?

Is it possible?

Comment: Sadly I cannot use PHP, it's a remote command it has to be done in one sql statement/query

Comment: Ohhh my bad its select statement chk my other mate answer.

Comment: UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='http://example.com' WHERE post_id= SELECT postid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name='hello-world'.... like that

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
  JOIN wp_posts 
    ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.post_id
SET wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'http://example.com'
WHERE wp_posts.post_name = 'hello-world'
```

Comment: my answer is for MySql, not sure what db are you using because your original question has two db.

Comment: U r genious what about my mentioned query in comment I hope this will also work?

Comment: @devpro probably will work too, but will be slower because have to do a subquery for each row.  This way do the matching on one step.

Comment: Hmm thats y I decided to not post as an answer. Yur answer is best one

Answer (score 0):

`IN` works also

```
UPDATE  wp_postmeta
SET     meta_value = 'http://example.com'
WHERE   post_id IN (SELECT  id
                    FROM    wp_posts
                    WHERE   post_name = 'hello-world')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use join or sub queries. I presonally prefer joins.

I would write your query like this :

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta AS C1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts AS C2 ON  C1.post_id = C2.post_id
SET meta_value='http://example.com'
WHERE C1.column_name = "search criteria";
```